# Error occurred while initializing fusion

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net

I'm getting an error when I try to install .NET 2.0 on my Server 2003 SP1;

```
Error 25007.Error occurred while initializing fusion.
Setup could not load fusion with LoadLibraryShim()
```

.NET-Framework 1.1 is already installed, is that the problem? I always thought you can just override any older installations of .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced this problem and I tried each of the following. I'll start with the least intrusive solutions.  You can try installing after each one:

- .NET Framework Cleanup Tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/pages/8904493.aspx
- Delete the folder: %windir%\WinSxS\Policies
- Solving setup errors by using the SubInACL tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/09/04/739820.aspx
- Some other solutions people have tried: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/47c93410-2ee2-4dd1-812a-04475d50de7c/

--

[EDIT] This problem happened after I got a Windows Update for Visual Studio SP1.  I uninstalled Visual Studio and reinstalled .NET 2.0 framework and everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when an installer for another application started installing Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 (such application required it).

I solved closing such installer, installing Windows Imaging Component in my operating system language (it's a prerequisite for .NET 4), then **installing Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 (downloading it from Microsoft site)** and finally launching again the installer above.